# Why does CrudRepository.save(…) return a value?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

This is a curiosity question based on the fact that in Java everything is passed by value. The signature of the `save` method is:

```
<S extends T> S save(S entity);
```

Say I have this code :

```
MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
entity.setId(null);
entity.setName("entity");

MyEntity savedEntity = repository.save(entity);
```

When calling `repository.save(entity)`, isn't `entity` updated in the `save` method? I mean at the end of `save` execution, `savedEntity` and `entity` have the same state, so why returning it ?

Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S- *"Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely."*

Comment: @luk2302 I updated my question to be clearer. I already read the doc too.

Comment: That's because during INSERT statement in db values for some columns can be generated. For example uuid or timestamp.

Comment: @SergeyVasnev I took a look at the `save` implementation, internally it uses `EntityManager#persist(..)` method which returns nothing `public void persist(Object entity)`

Comment: Its easier to follow code that acts like objects are immutable even when they aren't.